# Coq rewriting using lambda arguments

Tags: coq, proof

We have a function that inserts an element into a specific index of a list.

```
Fixpoint inject_into {A} (x : A) (l : list A) (n : nat) : option (list A) :=
  match n, l with
    | 0, _        => Some (x :: l)
    | S k, []     => None
    | S k, h :: t => let kwa := inject_into x t k
                     in match kwa with
                          | None => None
                          | Some l' => Some (h :: l')
                        end
  end.
```

The following property of the aforementioned function is of relevance to the problem (proof omitted, straightforward induction on `l` with `n` not being fixed):

```
Theorem inject_correct_index : forall A x (l : list A) n,
  n <= length l -> exists l', inject_into x l n = Some l'.
```

And we have a computational definition of permutations, with `iota k` being a list of nats `[0...k]`:

```
Fixpoint permute {A} (l : list A) : list (list A) :=
  match l with
    | []     => [[]]
    | h :: t => flat_map (
                  fun x => map (
                             fun y => match inject_into h x y with
                                        | None => []
                                        | Some permutations => permutations
                                      end
                           ) (iota (length t))) (permute t)
  end.
```

The theorem we're trying to prove:

```
Theorem num_permutations : forall A (l : list A) k,
  length l = k -> length (permute l) = factorial k.
```

By induction on `l` we can (eventually) get to following goal: `length (permute (a :: l)) = S (length l) * length (permute l)`. If we now simply `cbn`, the resulting goal is stated as follows:

```
length
  (flat_map
     (fun x : list A =>
      map
        (fun y : nat =>
         match inject_into a x y with
         | Some permutations => permutations
         | None => []
         end) (iota (length l))) (permute l)) =
length (permute l) + length l * length (permute l)
```

Here I would like to proceed by `destruct (inject_into a x y)`, which is impossible considering `x` and `y` are lambda arguments. Please note that we will never get the `None` branch as a result of the lemma `inject_correct_index`.

How does one proceed from this proof state? (Please do note that I am not trying to simply complete the proof of the theorem, that's completely irrelevant.)

Comment: A [mcve] with all the imports would help us to help you :)

Comment: @AntonTrunov It would be possible to make it slightly more minimal, hopefully 2 definitions is within reason.

Comment: You may want to rewrite with `Lemma eq_map X Y (f g : X -> Y) l : (forall x, f x = g x) -> map f l = map g l.
Proof.
intros h_eq; induction l as [|x l ihl]; [easy|].
now simpl; rewrite h_eq, ihl.
Qed.
` and similarly for `flat_map`. This way, you can assert the needed extensional equality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a way to rewrite under binders: the `setoid_rewrite` tactic (see [§27.3.1](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual030.html#sec787) of the Coq Reference manual).

However, **direct** rewriting under lambdas is not possible without assuming an axiom as powerful as the axiom of functional extensionality ([`functional_extensionality`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.html#functional_extensionality)).

Otherwise, we could have proved:

```
(* classical example *)
Goal (fun n => n + 0) = (fun n => n).
  Fail setoid_rewrite <- plus_n_O.
Abort.
```

See [here](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2005-02/msg00002.html) for more detail.

Nevertheless, if you are willing to accept such axiom, then you can use the approach described by Matthieu Sozeau in [this](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.logic.coq.club/3587) Coq Club post to rewrite under lambdas like so:

```
Require Import Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.
Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.
Require Import Coq.Classes.Morphisms.

Generalizable All Variables.

Instance pointwise_eq_ext {A B : Type} `(sb : subrelation B RB eq)
  : subrelation (pointwise_relation A RB) eq.
Proof. intros f g Hfg. apply functional_extensionality. intro x; apply sb, (Hfg x). Qed.

Goal (fun n => n + 0) = (fun n => n).
  setoid_rewrite <- plus_n_O.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: I find the answer helpful. I ended up using the setoid_rewrite. Sadly there's no setoid_destruct (not that it makes any sense...).

Comment: Thanks! Btw, if it were up to me then in your *particular* situation I'd settle for the approach @ejgallego pointed out.

Comment: I have tried to reconstruct this - what exactly did you setoid_rewrite with? It seems that the only thing that would help here is to actually destruct the  `match inject_into h x y` but as @ScarletAmaranth has pointed out, `setoid_destruct` is non sequitur.

Comment: @AntlerM Does [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anton-trunov/8d4a1360bee9d1c160c6de0bd41d2147) work for you?

Comment: @AntonTrunov It does, thanks a lot! I had to read up about the Instance shenenigans, one does not simply setoid_rewrite right away. Thanks again.

Comment: @AntlerM Sorry for the confusion, I mislead Anton into believing that `forall x y, inject_into a x y = Some x`; of course what you're supposed to have is `forall x y, y <= length x -> exists x', inject_into a x y = Some x'`, as per the correct_index lemma. To make inject_into total with `n : nat` and not some kind of horrible dependent `Fin (length l)`, the definition just returns `None` without proof if the index used for insertion is silly.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth Oh ok, but then I cannot rewrite with something of form `exists x, P(x) = P'(X)`.