# Struggling with functional extensionality

Tags: function, coq, proof

I've been programming in Coq for a few months now. Particularly, I'm interested in functional programming proofs where functions arise everywhere (*optics*, *state monad*, etc.). In this sense, dealing with *functional extensionality* has become essential, though extremely annoying. To illustrate the situation, let us assume a simplication of `Monad` (just one law defined):

```
Class Monad (m : Type -> Type) :=
{ ret : forall {X}, X -> m X
; bind : forall {A B}, m A -> (A -> m B) -> m B
}.
Notation "ma >>= f" := (bind ma f) (at level 50, left associativity).

Class MonadLaws m `{Monad m} :=
{ right_id : forall X (p : m X), p >>= ret = p }.
```

Now, I'd like to prove that chaining several `ret`s to a program `p` should be equivalent to the very same program:

```
Example ugly_proof :
  forall m `{MonadLaws m} A (p : m A), 
    p >>= (fun a1 => ret a1 >>= (fun a2 => ret a2 >>= ret)) = p.
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct H0 as [r_id].

  assert (J : (fun a2 : A => ret a2 >>= ret) =
              (fun a2 : A => ret a2)).
  { auto using functional_extensionality. }
  rewrite J.

  assert (K : (fun a1 : A => ret a1 >>= (fun a2 : A => ret a2)) =
              (fun a1 : A => ret a1)).
  { auto using functional_extensionality. }
  rewrite K.

  now rewrite r_id.
Qed.
```

The proof is correct, but the iterative `assert` pattern makes it very cumbersome. Indeed, it becomes impractical when things get more complex, as you can find in [this proof](https://github.com/hablapps/koky/blob/master/Core/affine.v#L68-L226) (which evidences that an affine traversal is closed under composition).

Having said so, what is the best way of implementing the aforementioned proof? Is there any project or article (more approachable than [this one](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.html)) around functional extensionality to be taken as reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an approach with `setoid_rewrite` tactic (I tried to demostrate it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43853467/2747511)):

```
Require Import Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.
Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.
Require Import Coq.Classes.Morphisms.

Generalizable All Variables.

Instance pointwise_eq_ext {A B : Type} `(sb : subrelation B RB eq)
  : subrelation (pointwise_relation A RB) eq.
Proof. intros f g Hfg. apply functional_extensionality. intro x; apply sb, (Hfg x). Qed.

Example easy_proof `{ml : MonadLaws m} `{p : m A} :
  p >>= (fun a1 => ret a1 >>= (fun a2 => ret a2 >>= ret)) = p.
Proof. now repeat setoid_rewrite right_id. Qed.
```

Reading material:

- [A Gentle Introduction to Type Classes and Relations in Coq](http://www.labri.fr/perso/casteran/CoqArt/TypeClassesTut/typeclassestut.pdf) by Pierre Castéran & Matthieu Sozeau
- [A New Look at Generalized Rewriting in Type Theory](https://www.irif.fr/~sozeau//research/publications/A_New_Look_at_Generalized_Rewriting_in_Type_Theory.pdf) by Matthieu Sozeau

Comment: I've seen several references to *setoid*, but I haven't gone deeper into it. Thereby, I'm going to accept the other answer for now, which is way far more approachable to me. Is there any introductory material to learn about this library? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to generalize `right_id` law a bit:

```
Require Import Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.
Generalizable Variables m A.

Lemma right_id_gen `{ml : MonadLaws m} `{p : m A} r :
  r = ret -> p >>= r = p.
Proof. intros ->; apply ml. Qed.
```

Now we can use backward reasoning:

```
Example not_so_ugly_proof `{ml : MonadLaws m} `{p : m A} :
  p >>= (fun a1 => ret a1 >>= (fun a2 => ret a2 >>= ret)) = p.
Proof.
  apply right_id_gen, functional_extensionality; intros.
  apply right_id_gen, functional_extensionality; intros.
  now apply right_id_gen.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the RHS to `p >>= ret` and reason backwards with `f_equal`, changing the goal to `(fun _ => ...) = ret` where `functional_extensionality` is applicable.

```
Class MonadLaws m `{Monad m} :=
  { right_id : forall X (p : m X), p >>= ret = p }.
Example ugly_proof :
  forall m `{MonadLaws m} A (p : m A), 
    p >>= (fun a1 => ret a1 >>= (fun a2 => ret a2 >>= ret)) = p.
Proof.
  intros.
  transitivity (p >>= ret).
  rewrite <- (right_id _ p) at 2.
  f_equal.
  apply functional_extensionality.
  intro x.
  rewrite <- (right_id _ (ret x)) at 2.
  f_equal.
  apply functional_extensionality.
  intro x0.
  rewrite <- (right_id _ (ret x0)) at 2.
  auto.
Qed.
```