# setoid_rewrite fails in pattern matching scenario

Tags: pattern-matching, coq, substitution

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49539331/1263978), I was told how to
use `setoid_rewrite` to deal with *functional_extensionality*. Unluckily, I've
found that this nice solution doesn't work in the following scenario. Suppose
that we've defined a `Monoid` class:

```
Class Monoid (m : Type) :=
{ mzero : m
; mappend : m -> m -> m
}.
Notation "m1 * m2" := (mappend m1 m2) (at level 40, left associativity).

Class MonoidLaws m `{Monoid m} :=
{ left_unit  : forall m, mzero * m = m (* ; other laws... *) }.
```

If we add [`pointwise_eq_ext`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49540309/1263978) in
the picture, `monoid_proof` becomes trivial:

```
Require Import Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.
Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.
Require Import Coq.Classes.Morphisms.

Generalizable All Variables.

Instance pointwise_eq_ext {A B : Type} `(sb : subrelation B RB eq)
  : subrelation (pointwise_relation A RB) eq.
Proof.
  intros f g Hfg.
  apply functional_extensionality.
  intro x.
  apply sb.
  apply (Hfg x).
Qed.

Example monoid_proof `{ml : MonoidLaws m} :
  (fun m => mzero * m) = (fun m => m).
Proof. now setoid_rewrite left_unit. Qed.
```

However, if the same monoid expression appears as an argument for `option_fold`,
the tactic fails:

```
Definition option_fold {A B} (some : A -> B) (none : B) (oa : option A) : B :=
  match oa with
  | Some a => some a
  | None => none
  end.

(* Expression is an argument for [option_fold] *)
Example monoid_proof' `{ml : MonoidLaws m} :
  forall om,
    option_fold (fun m => mzero * m) mzero om = option_fold (fun m => m) mzero om.
Proof. intros. now setoid_rewrite left_unit. (* error! *) Qed.
```

I'm not familiar with the details of `setoid_rewrite`, but it seems that the
pattern matching is conforming a context which is preventing this tactic to
execute properly. Is there any way to teach `setoid_rewrite` how to deal with
this kind of situations? I've been trying to provide several `subrelation`
instances, but I lack the theoretical background to understand the whole
picture. A general solution would be awesome, but I'd be happy enough with an
*ad hoc* approach to rewrite expressions in the arguments of (nested)
invocations of `option_fold`.

Comment: I cannot get your code to run. Could you please include in your question all the necessary definitions?

Comment: Sure, there you have it! I've published [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jeslg/26fe0a4bb6dbe16d96fa9c58353ac8b5) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pointwise_eq_ext` instance lets you to rewrite in the goals like this one:

```
(fun m => mzero * m) = (fun m => m)
```

but things break if you have your function inside some context. To fix this you need to add the following subrelation:

```
Instance subrel_eq_respect {A B : Type}
         `(sa : subrelation A RA eq)
         `(sb : subrelation B eq RB) :
   subrelation eq (respectful RA RB).
Proof. intros f g -> a a' Raa'. apply sb. f_equal. apply (sa _ _ Raa'). Qed.
```

You might want to take a look at the full code in [this Coq Club post](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.logic.coq.club/3587) by Matthieu Sozeau.

Comment: I saw that post, but this `subrelation` wasn't helping in my [affine traversal proof](https://github.com/hablapps/koky/blob/master/Core/affine.v#L81-L92). It seems that it contains additional "contexts" which are preventing `setoid_rewrite` to execute properly, so I'll keep on delimiting the problem. Anyway, I didn't notice that it solves this particular situation. Many thanks Anton!

Comment: @jeslg Can you make a standalone example with the failing rewrite? I can take a look at it.